# Exclude last matching portion of the text

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I'm trying to figure out a regular expression to match all but the last occurrence of a particular group (namely the parentheses-enclosed common name, if present). The data is sadly not particularly well formatted, but it's out of my control.

Here's the expected input `->` the expected output

```
Homo sapiens (human) -> Homo sapiens
mitochondrion Capra hircus (goat) -> mitochondrion Capra hircus
Escherichia coli -> Escherichia coli
Xenopus (Silurana) tropicalis (western tree frog) -> Xenopus (Silurana) tropicalis
```

I tried a positive lookahead, but it failed on *case 3* because there is no common name given. Trying to match `([^()]*)` and capturing *group 0* doesn't work on *case 4*, and I'm wary of trying to stitch the matched groups together because I can't guarantee the parentheses-enclosed scientific name [i.e. `'(Silurana)'`] will fall between the *genus* `(Xenopus)` and *species* `(tropicalis)`.

Comment: Must the solution be done in a single regular expression? It's often easier to do a "close enough" match, and then do some further processing, such as stripping out anything in parenthesis at the end of the match.

Comment: @BryanOakley, if I understand it correctly, according to the third example, it should match.

Comment: @ndn: Thanks. I somehow missed seeing the third example. I've updated my comment.

Comment: If you are sure you don't need the last part enclosed in parenthesis at the end of the string, remove it with a replacement.

Comment: @BryanOakley, no, it need not be done in a singular regular expression, but I wasn't sure how else to approach it.

Comment: @Emmett: is `Xenopus (Silurana) tropicalis` a possible item?

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte: yes, that is a real frog that the program will need to handle.

Comment: @Emmett: I ask that because this time the item doesn't have parenthesis at the end but parenthesis (you need to keep) in the middle.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte: Ah, I missed the distinction. I'm not certain a case like that, with internal parentheses but not the ending ones, will come up, but I strongly suspect it's a possibility (people get crazy with their scientific names, and GenBank is not the most consistent source).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A non-regex solution is quite trivial:

```
start, _, end = text.rpartition('(')
result = start or end
```

`rpartition` will search the string from the end and at the first `(` it returns the triplet `(text-before, separator, text-after)` where `separator = '('` in this case. In the case where no `(...)` is in the string you have that everything is inside `text-after` and `text-before` and `separator` are both empty strings.
When there is a `(...)` you'll have all the text before the last `(` in `text-before`, the separator is `(` and `text-after` will be `...)`.

Thus `start or end` always contains the value you need. If `start` is non-empty you want that, otherwise the result is in `end`.

Alternatively:

```
result = next(filter(None, text.rpartition('(')))
```

Sample run:

```
In [1]: texts = [
   ...:     'Homo sapiens (human)',
   ...:     'mitochondrion Capra hircus (goat)',
   ...:     'Escherichia coli',
   ...:     'Xenopus (Silurana) tropicalis (western tree frog)',
   ...: ]

In [2]: for text in texts:
   ...:     start, _, end = text.rpartition('(')
   ...:     print('in {!r}\t->\t{!r}'.format(text, start or end))
   ...:     
in 'Homo sapiens (human)'       ->      'Homo sapiens '
in 'mitochondrion Capra hircus (goat)'  ->      'mitochondrion Capra hircus '
in 'Escherichia coli'   ->      'Escherichia coli'
in 'Xenopus (Silurana) tropicalis (western tree frog)'  ->      'Xenopus (Silurana) tropicalis '

In [3]: for text in texts:
   ...:     print('in {!r}\t->\t{!r}'.format(text, next(filter(None, text.rpartition('(')))))
in 'Homo sapiens (human)'       ->      'Homo sapiens '
in 'mitochondrion Capra hircus (goat)'  ->      'mitochondrion Capra hircus '
in 'Escherichia coli'   ->      'Escherichia coli'
in 'Xenopus (Silurana) tropicalis (western tree frog)'  ->      'Xenopus (Silurana) tropicalis '
```

Timings:

```
In [13]: texts *= 1000

In [14]: %%timeit
    ...: results = []
    ...: for text in texts:
    ...:     start, _, end = text.rpartition('(')
    ...:     results.append(start or end)
    ...: 
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.04 ms per loop
```

Which is more than 4 times faster than the regex-based solution:

```
In [15]: import re

In [16]: %%timeit regex = re.compile(r'^(?:(?!.*\(.*\)).*|.*(?= \(.*\)))')
    ...: results = []
    ...: for text in texts:
    ...:     match = regex.match(text)
    ...:     results.append(match.group(0))
    ...: 
100 loops, best of 3: 4.27 ms per loop
```

The `filter` version is slightly slower than the `or` solution:

```
In [19]: %%timeit
    ...: results = []
    ...: for text in texts:
    ...:     results.append(next(filter(None, text.rpartition('('))))
    ...: 
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.89 ms per loop
```

Comment: I always prefer a few lines of code over regex. Regex is completely unreadable unless you're using it every day. And the fact that this code is faster than the regex is icing on the cake. Nice job!

Answer (score 1):

```
^(?:(?!.*\(.*\)).*|.*(?= \(.*\)))
```

[See it in action](http://pythex.org/?regex=%5E(%3F%3A(%3F!.*%5C(.*%5C)).*%7C.*(%3F%3D%20%5C(.*%5C)))&test_string=Homo%20sapiens%20(human)%0Amitochondrion%20Capra%20hircus%20(goat)%0AEscherichia%20coli%0AXenopus%20(Silurana)%20tropicalis%20(western%20tree%20frog)%0A&ignorecase=0&multiline=1&dotall=0&verbose=0)

The idea is that you want to match either an entire line, which does not have something in brackets:

```
(?!.*\(.*\)).*
```

or everything up until the last space, followed by something in brackets:

```
.*(?= \(.*\)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this out

```
(.+)(?:\(.+\))$|(.+)
```

**`(.+)(?:\(.+\))$:`** looks for parentheses  with words at the end of the line and matches what comes before it.

**`(.+):`** matches anything every character except a newline.

Then Capture `group 1` and `group 2`

**Output**

```
Homo sapiens 
mitochondrion Capra hircus 
Escherichia coli
Xenopus (Silurana) tropicalis
```

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/aJ3aW4/1)

Comment: Good approach. Though it gets `"Escherichia "` and `"coli\n"` as separate matches. Use `(.+)` instead for the second alternation.